# Coerce xts to ts in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts

I have `xts` time-series object for 10 days of data. The data is sampled at minutes frequency. Therefore, for each day, I have 1440 observations. I need to coerce `xts` to `ts` object so that I can use `stl` function as used in the [example](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/6/1). But, On coercion, R generates error as

```
ts(min_data,start=start(min_data),end = end(min_data),frequency=10)
Error in ts(min_data, start = start(min_data), end = end(min_data), frequency = 10) : 
  invalid time series parameters specified
```

I set frequency to 10, since I am using data of 10 days. I am not sure whether it should be 10 or 1440. Can anyone help me to fix this error.

MWE is as

```
library(xts)
timevalues="20150101 0000/20150110 2359"
timesequence<- timeBasedSeq(timevalues)
min_data<-xts(rnorm(14400),timesequence)
ts_data<- ts(min_data,start=start(min_data), end = end(min_data),frequency=10)
```

**UPDATE**
Although I am able to plot the graph using `stl` function as suggested by @Pascal, but still I am missing the time component in the x-axis of the graph. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you want to do with a `ts` object, but you should keep your `xts` to manage your 10-minute data. Or if you really need a `ts` object, I guess the closest you will get is with `as.ts(min_data)`.

Comment: I want to use `stl()` function of the basic stats package. I tried `as.ts()` as well

Comment: Then try `ts_data <- ts(as.numeric(min_data), frequency = 1440); plot(stl(ts_data, s.window = "per"))`.

Comment: Thanks, it solves one part of the problem. But, important part of information is lost, i.e., timestamp. I am following example from /www.otexts.org/fpp/6/1. Anyways I need to work on the timestamp part

Comment: So please make your question specific next time. You didn't say neither you want to use `stl` nor you want to work on timestamp in your OP. However, your time stamp are `timesequence`, as `NROW(stl(ts_data, s.window = "per")$time.series)` is `14400`.

Comment: Sorry. I will take care. I want to show the time/dates in the x-axis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(xts)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

set.seed(42)
timevalues = "20150101 0000/20150110 2359"
timesequence <- timeBasedSeq(timevalues)
min_data <- xts(rnorm(14400),timesequence)

ts_data <- ts(as.numeric(min_data), frequency = 1440)
out <- stl(ts_data, s.window = "per")
time.series <- as.data.frame(cbind(ts_data, out$time.series))
colnames(time.series) <- c("Data", "Seasonal", "Trend", "Remainder")
time.series$Date <- timesequence
time.series <- melt(time.series, 'Date')

ggplot(time.series, aes(x=Date, y=value)) + 
  geom_line() +
  facet_free(variable~.)
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I recently have discovered a package called "tsbox".

It promises easy conversion between time series types.
(here a tutorial: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tsbox/vignettes/tsbox.html)

Might be useful in cases like this one.

Here an example:

```
library(tsbox)
nowTS <-ts_ts(formerXTS)
```

or the other way round if you want to convert the ts back to an xts series

```
library(tsbox)
nowXTS <-ts_xts(nowTS)
```

Comment: Handy package. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

An xts-only solution, based on an idea I had from looking at [Pascal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35715504/271616).

```
library(xts)
set.seed(42)
timevalues = "20150101 0000/20150110 2359"
timesequence <- timeBasedSeq(timevalues)
min_data <- xts(rnorm(14400),timesequence)

ts_data <- ts(as.numeric(min_data), frequency = 1440)
out <- stl(ts_data, s.window = "per")

ts_out <- merge(min_data, out$time.series)
plot.zoo(ts_out)
```

[image]

Comment: Should I infer from your answer that it is impossible to retain both data and index in `ts` object while coercing from `xts` object

Comment: @HaroonRashid: `ts` objects do not have an index like xts/zoo objects do. They don't need one, because `ts` objects can only contain strictly regular data. So they just have an attribute with the start, end, and interval. `print.ts` can print the times nicely for yearly, quarterly, and monthly data, but I'm not sure they can print intraday times nicely.

Answer (score 1):

If you hav a xts data in monthly, quarterly and yearly frequency it maby be useful (use packages: xts, stats, data.table, zoo)

```
xts_ts <- function(xts_data) {
  freq_list <-
    data.table::data.table(
      freq = c('month', 'quarter', 'year'),
      freq_n = c(12L, 4L, 1L),
      freq_format = c('%Y, %m', '%Y, %q', '%Y')
    )

  d_ferq <- xts::periodicity(xts_data)[["label"]]
  freq_n <- freq_list[freq == d_ferq, freq_n]
  freq_format <- freq_list[freq == d_ferq, freq_format]

  # Put NA if missing date
  empty <-
    zoo::zoo(order.by = seq.Date(zoo::index(xts_data)[1], zoo::index(xts_data)[nrow(xts_data)], by = d_ferq))
  no_misssing <- merge(xts_data, empty)

  if (d_ferq == 'quarter') {
    start_date <-
      format(zoo::as.yearqtr(xts::periodicity(xts_data)[["start"]]), freq_format)

  } else {
    start_date <-
      format(zoo::as.Date(xts::periodicity(xts_data)[["start"]]), freq_format)
  }

  stats::ts(zoo::coredata(no_misssing),
     start = as.integer(strsplit(start_date, split = ',')[[1]]),
     frequency = freq_n)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for is the below:

```
xts2ts <- function(XD) {
             maxRow <- nrow(XD)
             startYM <- c(.indexyear(XD[1]) + 1900, .indexmon(XD[1]) + 1L)
             endYM <- c(.indexyear(XD[maxRow]) + 1900, .indexmon(XD[maxRow]) + 1L)
             ts(as.numeric(XD), start = startYM, end = endYM, frequency = 12L)
}
```